# Creating an IFERROR using INDEX/MATCH formula in VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I have a VBA tool I'm trying to update by inputting an `IFERROR` formula into column B on Sheet2 using `INDEX`/`MATCH` to pull the data from column F in Sheet 1.  The matching criteria is looking at column D in the active row of Sheet 2 and matching it to Column J in Sheet 1.

The resulting formula should look like this

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$F:$F,MATCH('Sheet2'!$D2,Sheet1!$J:$J,0)),"")
```

This is the code I wrote but I'm getting the "`Unable to set formulaaray property of the range class`" error.

```
Range("B2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1,C6,MATCH(RC2,Sheet1,RC10,0)),"""")"
```

I'm still rather new to VBA and in my research I haven't found anything to help.  Appreciate any help anyone can give me in solving this error.

I'm trying to adapt/change the current formula coded in the tool to the above.  This code was working it's just the user has made some changes to the file and now wants to grab the data as described in my original post.

```
Range("B2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(C6,MATCH(RC1&R1C2,C1&C5,0)),"""")": Range("B2:B" & LastRow).FillDown
        Range("B:b").EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Why do you need an array formula? Is simple Range.Formula not sufficient?

Comment: Your formula is not an array formula. Could you share your complete code? Also, you are mixing *A1-style* and *R1C1-style* references which is not allowed. What is `HTP`?

Comment: When you show us **how formula should look like**, you should try the VBA version to obtain **a similar/identic string**. How could we imagine what 'HTP' means, also a `Match` function with 4 parameters, a mix between the A1 and R1C1 style... Anything does not try building the reference formula. We cannot help if we cannot understand what you try accomplishing.

Comment: My apologies I had adjusted my formulas to use basic sheet names from what the sheet names are in my file I'm updating but forgot to change it in my code.  HTP is the name of the sheet I'm referencing in my file.  I've updated the verbiage above so HTP was replaced with Sheet1.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt/change the current formula coded in the tool to the above.  This code was working it's just the user has made some changes to the file and now wants to grab the data as described in my original post.

 Range("B2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(C6,MATCH(RC1&R1C2,C1&C5,0)),"""")": Range("B2:B" & LastRow).FillDown
            Range("B:b").EntireColumn.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Did you read and tried understanding the above clarification questions? You have been asked *Why a formula array?*, also I tried making you understand that the formula you try building in VBA must exactly lead to the one you show us as model. You have been warned that using two different formula styles is not allowed and so on... If you try `Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$F:$F,MATCH('Sheet2'!$D2,Sheet1!$J:$J,0)),"""")"` does it raise any error? Doesn't it return what you want?

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup (`INDEX/MATCH` formula)

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the results of an 'INDEX/MATCH' formula as values.
' Formula:      '=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$F:$F,MATCH(D2,Sheet1!$J:$J,0)),"")'
' Remarks:      'VLOOKUP' doesn't work because 'F' is to the left of 'J':
'               wrong '=VLOOKUP(D2,Sheet1!$J:$F,-5,0)' wrong.
' Calls:        'RefColumn'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub VBALookupFormula()

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const slCol As String = "J" ' 2. lookup (compare (match))
    Const svCol As String = "F" ' 3. value (return)
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dlCol As String = "D" ' 1. lookup (read)
    Const dvCol As String = "B" ' 4. value (write)
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = RefColumn(sws.Cells(sfRow, slCol))
    If slrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlrg As Range: Set dlrg = RefColumn(dws.Cells(dfRow, dlCol))
    If dlrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim slAddress As String: slAddress = slrg.Address
    Dim svAddress As String: svAddress = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol).Address
    
    Dim dlAddress As String: dlAddress = dlrg.Cells(1).Address(0, 0)
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dlrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    
    Dim dFormula As String
    ' Note the 4 single quotes (necessary when a worksheet name contains spaces)
    ' and the 4 consecutive double quotes (basically one double quote
    ' in the formula is two double quotes in VBA).
    dFormula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('" _
        & sName & "'!" & svAddress & ",MATCH(" & dlAddress & ",'" _
        & sName & "'!" & slAddress & ",0)),"""")"
    
    dvrg.Formula = dFormula
    dvrg.Value = dvrg.Value
    
    MsgBox "The lookup finished successfully.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```